# Omniture Tracking Codes Showing Up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, filtering

I have a website uses Adobe Omniture for web analytics.  We have some internal tools that automatically append Omniture tracking codes to links within specific modules.  Within those modules we link to a subdomain that is using Google Analytics.  However, GA is picking up the Omniture URL parameters and it's causing GA to interpret those as different pages.  For example, in the `Behavior > Site Content > Pages` report I'll see

- `/`
- `/?prop1=foo`
- `/?prop1=foo&prop2=bar`

Those three pages are actually the same page, just the last two have tracking codes appended.  **How would I go about getting those three pages to show up as just `/`?**

I spoke to someone and they suggested I use Filtering in GA.  Is this the correct/best approach?  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analytics has a feature for this called "Exclude URL Query Parameters".   From their [help document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en):

> Exclude URL Query Parameters: Any query parameters or unique session IDs (e.g., sessionid or vid) that appear in your URLs that you do not want to see in your reports. Enter as a comma-separated list.
>
> This setting is case sensitive. There is a 2048-character limit.

To use it you would:

1. Log into Google Analytics
2. Click **Admin**
3. Use the drop down menus to select the Account, Property, and View for which you want to apply this parameter list.
4. Click on **View Settings**
5. Enter your parameter list in the **Exclude URL Query Parameters** box:
   [image]

Comment: I'll give this a try once I get into the office. Thanks!

Comment: Are the exclusions retroactive?

Comment: I don't know for sure in this case, but changes to Google Anayltics are rarely retroactive.  The help document for view settings says that timezone changes are NOT retroactive, but it doesn't say anything about the other settings.